# Amazon API to get number of listings for a specific product

Tags: amazon-product-api

Is there an Amazon API, which can provide me with the total number of product listings based on a given search?

Comment: Does the [product advertising API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/) do what you need?

Comment: I haven't noticed, that I can get the number of listings. It will do. Thank you.